# Google Map API - Hello Word - error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Why 'hello word' example from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
makes this error?

[image: error message]

Here is my code :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 8
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>   </head>   <body> <div id="map-canvas"></div>   </body> </html>
```

Comment: This works fine for me if I either add my API_KEY or delete the key query string parameter.

Comment: i did the same ofcourse..

Comment: Of course. Just wanted to report it works in some scenarios as is.

Comment: You need to use a valid` API_KEY`  value as as `API_KEY`is just a placehodler for the code sample

Comment: It's obviously a bug in the experimental API-version. Load the release-version to fix it: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=API_KEY  You may report it at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Bug

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your HTML file is on your local filesystem which explains the error.

For security purpose, to avoid mixing element served on http and https by googleMap API, the javascript of the API is referencing external element starting with a double slash (ie : `//`) which would use the same protocol as the current HTML file.

As you are testing form the **local filesystem**, your url starts with `file://` and in consequence `//` would refer to `file://`

- In your case the javascript is make a request to `//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur` which would translate to `file://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur`
- on a **normal** http server it would translate to `http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur`
- on a https server would translate to `https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur`

Comment: Yes my html is in local file system, i need it this way for my QT project.
Is it possible without this error?

Comment: Maybe you can try with a [base url tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)